# How to write text after \part

Tags: parts

I am writing a report divided into parts. I would like to write a short description of each part on the same page as the part headline. When I just write:

```
\part{Hello}
Hello there...
```

The text "Hello there.." skips to the next page instead of the same. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 12):

You could make the text an optional argument to `\part` for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\let\old@endpart\@endpart
\renewcommand\@endpart[1][]{%
\begin{quote}#1\end{quote}%
\old@endpart}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Hello}
[Hello there...]

\chapter{zzz}
zzz


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Seems to work fine as long as the text fits on one page. If it is longer, it pulls the part heading down to the bottom of the page and has the text on the next pages. Any ideas how this can be avoided?

Answer (score 8):

It would be easy if you can use a KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setpartpreamble[u][\textwidth]{\vspace*{1cm}\blindtext}
\part{Hello}

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `memoir` class, which encompasses both the `book` and `report` classes,then:

```
\begin{document}
\nopartblankpage
% title pages, etc
\part{Title of the Part}
Some text on the Part page
\cleardoublepage % or \clearpage Text on the following blank page \clearpage
\clearpage
```

Comment: Gives an error: undefined control sequence \nopartblankpage

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, sneak in the textat the end. The text gets reset, so you don't use the same text twice by accident.

[image: teenPartText]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extraPartText}[1]{\def\@extraPartText{#1}}
\pretocmd{\@endpart}{\vspace{8ex}\begingroup\centering\@extraPartText\par\endgroup\let\@extraPartText\relax}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\extraPartText{Always be friendly to ducks, capybaras and wombats.}
\part{Wombat}

\chapter{Duck}
zzz

\part{Mara}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Somthing like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part[Hello]{{Hello\\[1cm] 
\large Hello there...}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Hello there` is now of part title, not a text :-) .