# How to place part titles to top of paper

Tags: sectioning, positioning, titlesec, parts

How to place part titles like chapter titles **in `book` class**?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{}
{\huge\bfseries Part \thepart} 
{8pt}
{\Huge\scshape}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\part{This is a part}
This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. 
\newpage
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

However, the spacing is too much – the part title doesn't appear at the top of the page but in the (near) center.

[image]

This is what I am looking for, coded in the most dirty way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\huge\bfseries Part 1}\\[8pt]
{\Huge\scshape This is a part}\par\vspace{2cm}
This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. 
\newpage 
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have looked at [How to write text after \part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336361/181261) for example, but all answers can't help me. I *have to use `book`*, and my description may contain two or more short paragraphs, with even some graphics included, so a macro is not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `\titlespacing`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\pagestyle{plain}\hrule height0pt}% to prevent extra blank line
{\huge\bfseries Part \thepart} 
{0pt}% distance between Part and title (plus normal spacing)
{\Huge\scshape}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-\topskip}{2cm}% distance before text

\begin{document}
\part{This is a part}
This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. This is a short description text. 
\newpage
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if I try to add a part (or a chapter) in an even page, it always get to an odd page. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: One way is `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`, but this also affects chapters.  You can temporaily turn off this feature using `\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage` in a group.