# How to put an image in \part page

Tags: graphics, memoir, parts

I am trying to put an image into the same page as the `\part` header, something like a sub-cover.

I tried something along the lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,ebook,italian,onecolumn,oneside,titlepage,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\title{Book Title}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\chapterstyle{companion}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part I Title}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PartIcover.jpg}
\chapter{First Chapter TItle}
```

This does not work well for two reasons:

- image is not right after "Part I Title", but on next page.
- in image page I get a spurious "INDEX  #" header (which is not present in `\part` page, of course)

Is it possible to achieve the desired effect? ("Part I Title" on top of page and image below it).

If so: how?

Note: I am almost a newbie to LaTeX, please be lenient.

*Update*:
following advice in comments I made the following; working, but fragile to say the least:

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\def\@partimage{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{\gdef\@partimage{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont #1\vfil\@partimage\vfil\gdef\@partimage{}}
\makeatother
...
\title{Book Title}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\chapterstyle{companion}
\tableofcontents
\partimage[width=210pt]{PartIcover.jpg}
\part{Part I Title}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PartIcover.jpg}
\chapter{First Chapter Title}
```

This is very fragile because I need to hand-compute remaining height after `\part` title.

I saw [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373312/167976), but I'm unsure how to use it in the above code.

Comment: take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40602/redefine-memoir-part-to-allow-image

Comment: @KJO: I had already tried that and it didn't work for me, but it turns out it was a my mistake: Image was too high to fit if scaled at `[width=\linewidth]`. What is the right spell to say "scale to fit in page"? (I currently put `[width=210pt]`, but that is *very* fragile).

Comment: `height=\textheight`. Try e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[angle=90,height=0.9\textheight]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485144/how-to-place-part-titles-to-top-of-paper/485154?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#485154

Comment: @marmot: it does not work as-is; apparently `\textheight` is the full height of text area, while I need "remaining height in current page". Any hint where I should look for that kind of data? I have seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373312/167976 but I'm unsure how to use it in my case. I will update question.

Comment: @marmot s approach is generally robust since in theory for a given page content not to float to next the page text height is the target boundary condition. By allowing say 5% for title we are left with 0.95 of text height for the image initially irrespective of aspect (so for a fixed landscape image) the secondary limit needs be text width thus in many cases leaving some following whitespace for text or second image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for essentially using the code I posted to SE about 40602 and 452089.

It is not clear to me whether you will be using the same or different graphics for each `\part` and how you want them placed on the page --- to fill the `\textwidth` or take up all the space below the part title text (you might not be able to have both). However, this may help (less any typos)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\@partimage{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{\gdef\@partimage{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont #1\vfil\@partimage\vfil\gdef  \@partimage{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\partimage[height=0.5\textheight,width =\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck-portrait.pdf}
\part{A Part}
\partimage[height=0.5\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck.pdf}
\part{Another Part}
\partimage[height=0.5\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck-portrait.pdf}
\part{Another Part}
\partimage[height=0.5\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck-portrait.pdf}
\part{The Third}
\end{document}
```

The above will fit an illustration on the same page as the `\part` heading constrained to be within the dimensions of half the `\textheigt` and the `\textwidth` while maintaining the aspect ratio of the illustration. The example illustrates how a different illustration can be applied to each `\part`.

GOM

Comment: Peter a few typo's snuck in so need `… \includegraphics[#1]{{#2}}} ` second example-image is a Puck? last example unknown=keepadspectratio

Comment: Many thanks for Your code; it works perfectly in plain latex->PDF, but now I'm trying to produce epub using `tex4ebook` and images simply disappear; can You help with [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/486029/167976)?

Comment: @KJO Thank you. Hopefully I have corrected the typos you pointed out. I have learned over the years that one cannot proofread ones own text..

Comment: @ZioByte Sorry, I can't help with that. Perhaps you could ask another question related to `tex4book`.

Comment: @PeterWilson I agree it is always easier to find fault with "others" work :-)