# Images disappearing when compiling with tex4ebook

Tags: graphics, memoir, tex4ebook

I am trying to convert an existing book from plain PDF output to ebook format for online publishing (and doing some reformatting in the process, but that's another question).

I have images in the `\part` page (thanks to @PeterWilson for that).
Problem is those images do not appear in tex4ebook output, without any error/warning.

Full (current) header of my book follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,ebook,italian,onecolumn,oneside,titlepage,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{quotmark}
\newcommand{\gqt}[1]{\tqt{\scshape #1}}
\newcommand{\stars}{\begin{center} * * *\\ \end{center}}
%
\makeatletter
\def\@partimage{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{\gdef\@partimage{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont #1\vfil\@partimage\vfil\gdef\@partimage{}}
\makeatother
%
\setlength\cftpartnumwidth{2em}
%
\author{Mauro Condarelli}
\title{Cronache della Nuova Terra}
\begin{document}
%
\frontmatter
\maketitle
%
\mainmatter
\chapterstyle{companion}
%\book{Cronache della Nuova Terra}
\tableofcontents
%
\partimage[width=210pt]{old_mage.jpg}
\part{In cerca di un Mondo Nuovo}
%
%
\chapter{La Missione}
%
%scene: 'Prologo I'

La Pianta non era certo imponente, somigliava a una verza troppo cresciuta, alta quasi un metro e mezzo e larga altrettanto, grandi foglie verde pallido sormontavano un tronco corto e tozzo dal quale partiva un robusto peduncolo che portava a una grossa zucca adagiata sulla sabbia pulita.\par
...
%end scene
%
%end chapter
%

\backmatter
\appendix
%
%
\end{document}
```

Problem, as said, is image (old-mage.jpg, in this case) simply vanishes leaving no visible trace.

I'm using a plain: `tex4ebook -c tex4book.cfg Cronache_della_Nuova_Terra.tex` to compile; contents of `tex4book.cfg` follows:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}   
\CoverMetadata{thano.jpg}
\Configure{AddCss}{blitz-lite.css}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.jpg,.pdf}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Any hint welcome

Comment: Does the .cfg file need to declare the graphics extensions BEFORE it sets the CoverMeta?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer: changing the order in .cfg and/or converting all images to .png (default format, AFAIK) does not change anything. Cover image is processed and present, images in `\partimage` are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tex4ht` redefines all sectioning commands, in order to provide a uniform configurable interface for all LaTeX classes. So the `\printparttitle` command is not used in `tex4ht`. Instead, the image can be printed in configuration for `\part`. Try the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\CoverMetadata{thano.jpg}
\Configure{AddCss}{blitz-lite.css}
\makeatletter
\Configure{part}
{}{}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h1 class="partHead"><span class="titlemark">}\partname \ \thepart \HCode{</span>}}
{\HCode{</h1>\Hnewline<aside class="partimage">}\@partimage\HCode{</aside>}\IgnoreIndent\par\OpfRegisterFile}
\makeatother
\Css{.partimage{margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}}
\Css{.partimage img{max-width:100\%;}}
\Css{.partHead .titlemark{display:block;}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.jpg,.pdf}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The most important part is in `\Configure{part}` from the manual:

> \Configure{unit} {top} {bottom} {before-title} {after-title}
>
> This command determines the content to be inserted at the mentioned locations of the  specified units.
>
> ```
> \Configure{chapter}
> {\HCode{<div class="chapter">}}  {\HCode{</div>}}
> {\HCode{<h2 class="chapterHead">}\chaptername
>     ~\thechapter\HCode{<br />}}
> {\HCode{</h2>}}
> ```

So we insert the image in the top insertion:

```
 \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<aside class="partimage">}\@partimage\HCode{</aside>}
```

The `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` is necessary to get the paragraphs right, `\HCode{<aside class="partimage">}\@partimage\HCode{</aside>}` then prints the image inside `<aside class="partimage">` element. This enables us to style it using CSS styles, as can be seen in the `\Css` commands.

The `\OpfRegisterFile` command is necessary for a correct page sequence. This command is provided by `tex4ebook` and registers current HTML file to a page sequence. The page with part title would be displayed at the end of file otherwise.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks; just a small issue: I would like to have image below title. Playing with top/bottom/before/after I managed to place image between "Parte I" and Title, but if I try to put it after Title strange things happen (i.e.: I get image for "Parte II" after "Parte I" or I don't get "Parte I" where it belongs, but it directly goes where "Parte II" should be... and "Parte II" is where I expect "Parte III"). Any hint?

Comment: @ZioByte I would insert it after  `</h1>` then. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks; tex4ebook seems very capable, unfortunately I was not able to find extensive documentation (just the very terse 'tex4ebook-doc.pdf') so I keep bumping into problems [next one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/486191/167976) has a separate Question.

Comment: @ZioByte most of the issues are shared with `tex4ht`, but it hasn't much better documentation. I am working on a new documentation for `tex4ht`: https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc it already contains lot of info about configuration