# Add image to part page - every image is the same

Tags: graphics, parts

#### Background

I keep a personal journal in LaTeX and would like to simplify my document.  I made a `\partpage` command to create my part pages:

[My part page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sti06.png)

Every part page has the same image.  Only their titles are different.

#### Question:

Is it possible to just use the `\part` command, and have LaTeX add the image for me?  I can then remove my custom command.  I looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485819/how-to-put-an-image-in-part-page) but don't understand how to integrate it.  My attempt has been commented in the MRE.  It doesn't seem to do anything; I assume it's because I'm using the `book` document class.

How do I make this work?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\partpage}[1]{%
    \part[#1]{%
        #1
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=1in]{Triforce1.png}
        \end{center}%
    }
}

%
% My attempt at integrating https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485938/118490
%
\makeatletter
\def\@partimage{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{\gdef\@partimage{\includegraphics[#1]{{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefon #1\vfil\@partimage\vfil\gdef  \@partimage{}}
\makeatother
%
% End attempt
%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\begin{document}
    \partimage[width=1in]{Triforce1.png}
    \partpage{partpage}
    \part[Part Title B]{Embedded \begin{center}\includegraphics[width=1in]{Triforce1.png}\end{center}}
    \part{Part Cmd} 
\end{document}
```

#### Using titlesec

I tried to use the `titlesec` package, which produced 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnzvi.png).  This is close; how do I move the image below the text?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx, titlesec}

%
% \titleformat{〈command〉}[〈shape〉]{〈format〉}{〈label〉}{〈sep〉}{〈before-code〉}[〈after-code〉]
% command:     \part
% shape:
% format:      \centering
% label:
% sep:         0pt
% before-code: image stuff
% after-code:  can't get to work?
%
\titleformat{\part}{\centering}{}{0pt}{
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=1in]{./Triforce1.png}
    \end{center}
}

%
% Using after-code: THIS ERRORS
%
%\titleformat{\part}{\Huge\centering}{}{0pt}{}[
%   \begin{center}
%       \includegraphics[width=1in]{./Triforce1.png}
%   \end{center}
%]

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\begin{document}
    \part{partpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: titlesec allows you do that.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I've updated my question.  Following https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en I tried `\titleformat`.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this go in the right direction? With the `explicit` option you can put the title in some environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\part}
[block] 
{\Large}
{\thechapter}
{10pt}
{\centering\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
   \Huge\sffamily #1\\
   \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-duck}
\end{tabular}}
[]

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\begin{document}
\part{partpage}

Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a little `\vspace{10pt}` after the `#1` to space the text and the picture.  This is great.  Thanks.

Comment: What is `\thechapter`?  I can't find it in the titlesec documentation

Comment: @Amy `\thechapter` is just the chapter number.