# Text and image on part page

Tags: memoir, parts

How can I have both text and image on the part page? I have tried the solution with

`\part{My part}[My long text below]`

Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872706/writing-text-on-latex-part-page and here: [How to write text after \part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336361/how-to-write-text-after-part).
But that cannot include images.

I have also tried to renew the command:

`\renewcommand*{\afterpartskip}{}`

But that doesn't work either. There's still a new page below the part title.

I use the memoir class.

Comment: (1) Please always provide a full but minimal example that others test without changing anything (instead of an image you can use `\rule{4cm}{4cm}`, (2) what exactly is `\part{My part}[My long text below]` suppose to do? None of the links you provide uses this syntax. (3) Perhaps you should start over and rephrase your question such taht others can see what you are doing and exactly what your goal is.

Comment: At minimum, it is necessary to know what `\documentclass` is being used.  Without that. no real answer is possible, only guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoir` manual talks about this, but perhaps not as clearly as it might do. Basically `\part{Title}` sets the part title and then calls `\partpageend` to finish off. By default it finishes the part title page immediately after setting the title. So, a simple example of what you want is:

```
% partprob.tex  SE 624485

\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\renewcommand{\partpageend}{} % don't force a new page after part title

\part{Your part}

\vspace{5\baselineskip}
Your long text below.

\cleardoublepage

Text after part page(s).

\end{document}
```

[image]